# Merging Jenkins MultiJob Projects

Tags: jenkins

I have a primary Jenkins multijob project that works beautifully to build a test environment. It contains nicely-organized multiphase steps that do a variety of things.

In order to make changes to this without impacting ongoing tests, I created a copy of the primary Jenkins project that is treated as a Dev copy.

However, I have no idea how to merge the changes from the Dev build down to my Main build.

Specifically, there are a few parts that have changed between the two MultiJob projects:

- Parameters - I've added a number of parameters to the overall MultiJob project.
- New multiphase jobs - I created a couple new multiphase jobs, these should transfer easy enough.

Is there any way to merge these changes that will save me from having to just reconstruct the parameters and such?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 possible ways:

1. You can rename the old job to a new name and then rename the new one to the old name, so you'll actually replace the old one with the new one.
2. Merge the config.xml files of those 2 jobs.